# How to call asp function on onclick event?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I want to call one asp function on onclick event.

```
<img src="..." style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="..." />
```

Here at `onclick` I want to call following function:

```
function getproject(valuenew)
    response.Cookies("projectname") = valuenew
end function
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Seriously, pick up a tutorial and read it, before you really start writing something.

Comment: but is it possible to call asp function on onclick ? or we cannot call server-side code from the client - all server-side code finishes executing before the client sees the response.

Comment: Now you are talking like a real beginner, instead of a totally outsider. Yes you can never run any server-side code on browser, but you can call a webpage, give it some parameters and get the result. If you want to do it without refresh the current webpage, then you have to try what we call ajax.

Comment: Handling cookies with a Client-Side function make sense in such case. e.g. JavaScript `function getproject(valuenew){/* cookie operations here */}` `... onclick="getproject('val')" ...`.

Comment: To call a serverside function from the clientside you will need to use AJAX.  Look into jQuery for examples.

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense to return to the server to set a cookie.  You can set a cookie very easily using JavaScript.  Here is an example:

```
var expire = new Date();
expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*5); // expire in 5 days

document.cookie="projectname=valuenew;expires=" +expire.toGMTString();
```

Here is a link with more info: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use ASP to set cookie, but I'll give you simple way to execute ASP code after clicking element.

First, add hidden frame to your page:

```
<iframe id="ajaxFrame" src="about:blank" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Now in the `onclick` have this:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('ajaxFrame').src = 'PageNameHere.asp?cookievalue=Your_New_Value_Here';"
```

And the last step, add this to your ASP code: (on top)

```
If Request.QueryString("cookievalue")<>"" Then
    getproject(Request.QueryString("cookievalue"))
    Response.END
End If
```

This is **not** the best practice, but as you're a beginner it's the most simple way I know of.. when you gain some experience look into real AJAX, most simple and powerful is [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: wow, why not show best practice.  This just seems like show off bad idea.

Comment: Feel free to post new answer with best practice. I went for something simple to understand and without using any libraries. And I did *mention* the best practice if the OP is willing to learn.

Comment: Cheers, you also got to it from different angle which is nice.